# PHP and MySQL get result as nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, multidimensional-array

I have these lines of code that populates a list of computers based on their manufacturer:

```
<?php 
$query = "
SELECT m.manufacturerName
     , c.id
     , c.computerName
     , GROUP_CONCAT(c.model SEPARATOR ',') clients
     , c.computerName 
  FROM manufacturers m 
  JOIN computers c 
    ON c.manufacturerId = m.id 
 GROUP  
    BY m.id;
";

    $manufacturers = array();

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $manufacturers[$row['manufacturerName']] = explode(',', $row['clients']);
        }
    }

    foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer => $clients) {
        echo '<div class="listview-outlook" data-role="listview">';
            echo '<div class="list-group">';
                echo '<a href="#" class="group-title">' . $manufacturer . '</a>';

                foreach ($clients as $client) {
                    echo '<div class="group-content">';
                        echo '<a href="/edit/computer.php?id=' . /* client id should be here */ . '" class="list">';
                            echo '<div class="list-content">' . $client  .'</div>';
                        echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }

            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

What should I do in order to present the result from the table column `c.id` inside the second foreach loop (line 20)?

I understand that I somehow need to build my arrays with the id, but how? I'm fairly new to programming so please bear with me!

Comment: Try `$manufacturer["id"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT m.manufacturerName, c.id, c.computerName, group_concat(c.model SEPARATOR ',') AS clients, c.computerName FROM manufacturers m ";
    $query .= "INNER JOIN computers c ON c.manufacturerId = m.id GROUP BY m.id";

    $manufacturers = array();

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $manufacturers[$row['manufacturerName']] = $row;
            $manufacturers[$row['manufacturerName']]['clients'] = explode(',', $row['clients']);
        }
    }

    foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer => $data) {
        echo '<div class="listview-outlook" data-role="listview">';
            echo '<div class="list-group">';
                echo '<a href="#" class="group-title">' . $manufacturer . '</a>';

                foreach ($data['clients'] as $client) {
                    echo '<div class="group-content">';
                        echo '<a href="/edit/computer.php?id=' . $data['id'] . '" class="list">';
                            echo '<div class="list-content">' . $client  .'</div>';
                        echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }

            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I get `computer.php?id=1` on all rows. Any idea on why? Thank's for your reply though.

Comment: Yeah that's because you you are putting a loop in a loop. The `$data['id']` is refering to the same `id` each result of the second loop. If this isn't correct, what is excacly you want to archieve?

Comment: Your query shows that a manufacturer have multiple models which you `concat` to clients. So it's true that if you loop in `manufacturers` through `clients` that all the clients in that manufacture has the same manufacture id right?

Comment: Yes it's true, maybe I was unclear in my initial question. Each client has it's own id (`c.id`) from the table `computers` wich I want to echo in each loop. Right now, it only echoes the first `c.id` of each manufacturergroup. Do you understand me?